# Excel Vba error: Definitions of property procedures for the same property are inconsistent

Tags: excel, vba, properties, custom-object

It must be something obvious but I'm stuck so maybe you guys can help me.

Consider the following code inside a VBA custom object:

```
Private pSkipTrade As Boolean
Property Let SkipTrade(value As Double):
    If value = 0 Then
        pSkipTrade = False
    Else
        pSkipTrade = True
    End If
End Property

Public Property Get SkipTrade() As Boolean
    SkipTrade = pSkipTrade
End Property
```

Can anyone help me?

tks in advance!

Comment: @DavidZemens. Believe it or not. I just learned how to do that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Private pSkipTrade As Boolean
Public Property Let SkipTrade(lSkipTrade As Boolean)
    pSkipTrade = lSkipTrade
End Property
Property Get SkipTrade() As Boolean
   SkipTrade = pSkipTrade
End Property
```

Somewhere else in your code you are using another variable (e.g., `value`) to set this property.  If this variable is not of Type `Boolean` (e.g., a `Long`, `Double`, or `Decimal`), then you can do something like:

```
Sub Test()
Dim MyObject As Object
Dim Value As Double               '## or, whatever

'# CREATE THE CLASS OBJECT
Set MyObject = New cMyObject  '## Modify to be your correct Type

Value = Application.InputBox("Enter any number")

'# ASSIGN THE PROPERTY VALUE BASED ON A LOCAL VARIABLE/LOGIC
'  use boolean logic to test whether "value = 0"
'  a non-zero value will return "True"
MyObject.SkipTrade = Not (CDbl(Value) = 0)

'# Display the value, so you can see that this is working correctly:
MsgBox "The value of SkipTrade is: " & MyObject.SkipTrade

End Sub
```

If you have multiple conditions, it would be better to use a `Function` call to return the property value, during the object's property assignment.

You can call a function like:

```
MyObject.SkipTrade = CheckSkipTrade(value)
```

With a function in your main code module like this, which could be modified to include any logic that you might need to incorporate:

```
Function CheckSkipTrade(value) As Boolean
Dim myVal as Boolean
    If IsNumeric(value) Then
       'returns true or false test whether 'value' = 0.
       myVal = Not(CDbl(value) = 0)
    Else:
        myVal = False

    End If

    '# Return the value of the function test:
    CheckSkipTrade = myVal
End Function
```

Notice that in the above example it is very explicit -- not hidden -- that you are directly making an assignment to the `SkipTrade` property of `MyObject` class object?  On the contrary, your method essentially calls a subroutine hidden away in the object module, that assigns a value to the property.  Does it work?  Yes.  Is it the best way to do it?  I don't think so; it a very confusing way of coding which will make later troubleshooting (especially if you hand this project off to someone else) that much more difficult.

Coding *explicitly* is better than coding *implicitly*.

Comment: but what if 'lSkipTrade' or 'value' is a double?

Comment: @AMariani it *can't* be a double, because you've declared the property `pSkipTrade As Boolean`. If you try to assign any non-bool type to this property, you will receive a mismatch error.

Comment: Is there a way around it? I actually want to define my pSkipTrade to be true of false depending if 'value' is zero or not (and other checks alike).

Comment: I do not think you understand how to use class objects :)  I will update with some more information for you.

Comment: I'm indeed getting to know objects. Can you see any problems in my proposed solution?

Comment: Yes. It's completely unnecessary. :)  Use boolean logic per my revised answer.  What you are doing is adding a public sub to the class object module to test the value of `Value` variable. THis is unnecessary, because you can just use one line of boolean logic to do this:  `MyObject.SkipTrade = Not (CDbl(Value) = 0)`

Answer (score 7):

The Let parameter has to match the return type of the Get property. See [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251357.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

So you need to change the parameter in Property Let to a Boolean type:

```
Private pSkipTrade As Boolean
Property Let SkipTrade(value As Boolean) '<--Parameter is Boolean type
   pSkipTrade = value 
End Property

Public Property Get SkipTrade() As Boolean
    SkipTrade = pSkipTrade
End Property
```

Then move the logic you had in your Let property to the code that uses the property:

```
If price = 0 Then
    SkipTrade = False
Else
    SkipTrade = True
End If
```